# Are power series the only series that could be used to approximate functions based on their derivatives at the point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, taylor-expansion, power-series

Could we use the Taylor-series derivation approach with some other base functions, not powers of x? Like exponent, logarithm, or something else? Is there something naturally fundamental about power functions that give their superposition this ability to approximate other functions that no other choice of base class of functions could provide? Or it's just a matter of convenience? I know about the Furier-series, but I'm more interested in this differentiation-derived Taylor-series approach at the moment. How general is it in terms of the choice of a base class of functions?

Comment: Just to respond to your initial query: Exponentials grow faster than any polynomial, and any power of a logarithm grows more slowly than the simplest polynomials, so it's hard to approximate the simplest functions. But perhaps you should specify in what sense you aim to *approximate functions based on their derivatives at a point*. What do you actually mean by a good approximation?

Comment: @TedShifrin in exactly the same sense like Taylor series does. Most introductions to derivation of Taylor series start from an assumption that we can somehow find coefficients of a power-series such that this power-series will approximate the function around the point. Why can't I assume that series based on some other functions could do the same trick?

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiation-based"?  As I see it, the Taylor series arises from starting by saying "let's make this function be a power series".  One then uses derivatives to figure out what the coefficients must be.  Are you asking for another type of series where one can also use derivatives to figure out the coefficients?  To make that work you'll need to know that differentiation plays nicely with the class of series you pick (like it does for power series), but even with that assumption it might not turn out that derivatives are the right tool for finding the coefficients.

Comment: I want a precise notion of what it means to approximate. For Taylor polynomials of degree $k$ you get the unique polynomial of degree $\le k$ that agrees with your function to order $k$ at $a$. That is, the error is small compared to $(x-a)^k$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle yes, you understand me correctly. So it seems like x^n is truly a unique function in a sense how it can be used to approximate other functions. In a way it's more fundamental than other functions since it can be used to produce other functions, but not the other way around. I think about it this way.

Comment: @user3537411 I think you might be overstating it a bit.  Lots of other functions can "produce" other functions (you've mentioned Fourier series already, for example).  You're specifically asking about getting at other functions *through differentiation*.  Differentiation is explicitly about linear approximation and (as Ted pointed out) is closely tied to best polynomial approximations, so it's maybe not so surprising that if you insist on differentiation as your main tool then you find yourself pushed towards power series.

Comment: @ChrisEagle oh, thank you! I didn't look at this connection between differentiation and polynomials from this perspective. I did know about linear approximations. But I think the hard part is to understand how it jumps from simple linear function approximation (which is just a reformulation of the Mean Value Theorem) to polynomials of a higher degree, thus not linear anymore. Now it seems to me that high degrees arise naturally from iterated differentiation, but it's still not too clear to me how to describe it mathematically. I think you should post this as an answer btw.

Comment: I think it would be much better to present Taylor Series as a natural extension of the simplest case of linear approximation through MVT. But all the sources I looked at present this polynomial structure as something given, rather than naturally arising. Thus it's not obvious to the learner why they choose polynomials in the first place. I for example always thought it was just a matter of convenience since polynomials are known to be very easy to work with.